# jquery unable to select element using next/closest

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML on my page;

```
<div id="c2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="expandCollapseSection" id="my_chk">
    <span>Header</span>
    <div style="" class="contentDiv">
        <div class="oj-inputtext oj-form-control oj-component">some things</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have the following JS code;

```
$(".expandCollapseSection").click(function (event) {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $(this).next('.contentDiv').slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        $(this).next('.contentDiv').slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

Now my question is `$(this).next('.contentDiv')` does not select the contentDiv

I even tried using `$(this).closest('.contentDiv')`

But still does not select.

Just to add `$(".contentDiv")` does get the div though.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @dsg No it is not a descendant. It is a sibling.

Comment: yes...it's a sibling

Comment: You need `$(this).nextAll('.contentDiv')` and use `change` instead of `click`

Answer (score 1):

use `siblings( ".selected" )`

```
$(".expandCollapseSection").click(function (event) {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $(this).siblings('.contentDiv').slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        $(this).siblings('.contentDiv').slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zxfhqfmp/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$(this).closest('div').find('.contentDiv');
```

```js
$(".expandCollapseSection").click(function (event) {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $(this).closest('div').find('.contentDiv').css({'color':'red'});
    } else {
        $(this).closest('div').find('.contentDiv').css({'color':'green'});
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="c2">
    <input type="checkbox" class="expandCollapseSection" id="my_chk">
    <span>Header</span>
    <div style="" class="contentDiv">
        <div class="oj-inputtext oj-form-control oj-component">some things</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="c3">
    <input type="checkbox" class="expandCollapseSection" id="my_chk">
    <span>Header</span>
    <div style="" class="contentDiv">
        <div class="oj-inputtext oj-form-control oj-component">some things</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

kapantzak's answer is correct.

However you could simply use

```
$(this).parent().find('.contentDiv');
```

Slightly more efficient, as you don't have to find closest div.

Answer (score 0):

Try This Code,

```
$(".expandCollapseSection").click(function (event) {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
        $(this).closest('#c2').find('.contentDiv').slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        $(this).closest('#c2').find('.contentDiv').slideUp('slow');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You may also use `nextAll` and shorten your code too, like below.

```
$(".expandCollapseSection").change(function (event) {
    var div = $(this).nextAll('.contentDiv');
    var func = this.checked ? 'slideDown' : 'slideUp';
    div[func]("slow");
});
```

Demo@[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/em8ox1t1/)

Comment: will it work for multiple context-specific checkboxex ?

Comment: Sure, as long as you have the `checkbox` and `div` grouped, such as the one you already have - `<div id="c2">...</div>`. But, again, it depends on your scenario. You may need to amend few things.